# gradle test --test option fails to generate xml reports

Tags: testing, gradle

With gradlew test task I am using "--tests" option to filter what tests to run to a single test package. Tests runs fine but it doesn't generate xml or html reports. These are just junit tests.

```
gradlew clean build test --tests com.mycompany.tests.abc*
```

If I exclude --test option, reports generated just fine.

Any work arounds?

Comment: what Gradle version are you using? I could not reproduce your behavior in versions 4.0 or 4.10 . Reports are always generated even when using `--tests` option

Comment: Are you sure there any tests in the given package? if not the task will fail and no reportes will be generated

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. This is part of jenkins and gradle tasks are calculated and passed as variables to 'invoke gradle script'. If I run just "gradlew test clean build", it works fine. But when I add "--test" parameter like "gradlew --test com.xxx.xx* clean build", it runs clean after running tests and the generated reports gets deleted when the next jenkins task 'publish junit test results' runs.